# Как выровнять 2 ряда блоков?

Tags: css3, html5

6 блоков в 2 ряда, нужно что бы верхний был ровно над нижним

```css
.icons {
    font-family: RobotoRegular;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    margin-top: 4%;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
}
.icons div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.icons div div {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 0 0px;
}
.icons img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
                    <div>
                        <div class="icon1">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon1.png">
                            <p>Более 5 лет на рынке</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon2">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon2.png">
                            <p>Сертификат ISO</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon3">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon3.png">
                            <p>Член международной ассоциации GALA</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="icon4">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon4.png">
                            <p>Более 500 постоянных клиентов</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon5">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon5.png">
                            <p>Более 12 000 часов устного перевода в год</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon6">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon6.png">
                            <p>Более 120 000 переведенных страниц в год</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блоку с классом icons задайте свойство flex-direction: column;

```css
.icons {
    font-family: RobotoRegular;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    margin-top: 4%;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.icons div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.icons div div {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 0 0px;
}
.icons img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
                    <div>
                        <div class="icon1">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon1.png">
                            <p>Более 5 лет на рынке</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon2">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon2.png">
                            <p>Сертификат ISO</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon3">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon3.png">
                            <p>Член международной ассоциации GALA</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="icon4">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon4.png">
                            <p>Более 500 постоянных клиентов</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon5">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon5.png">
                            <p>Более 12 000 часов устного перевода в год</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icon6">
                            <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon6.png">
                            <p>Более 120 000 переведенных страниц в год</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.icons {
  font-family: RobotoRegular;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  margin-top: 4%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(200px, auto));
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.icons div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div class="icon1">
    <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon1.png">
    <p>Более 5 лет на рынке</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon2">
    <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon2.png">
    <p>Сертификат ISO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon3">
    <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon3.png">
    <p>Член международной ассоциации GALA</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon4">
    <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon4.png">
    <p>Более 500 постоянных клиентов</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon5">
    <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon5.png">
    <p>Более 12 000 часов устного перевода в год</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon6">
    <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon6.png">
    <p>Более 120 000 переведенных страниц в год</p>
  </div>
</div>
```